# Автоподстановка в Эклипсе

Tags: ide, eclipse, c++

Я пишу под андроид. Проект пишется как на Java, так и на C++ (JNI). Проблема в том, что скачав CDT и прочее для C++, эклипс не подхватывает мои С++ классы, собственно и не классы тоже. Те у меня нет ни авто подстановки, ни авто дополнения, при этом на Java все хорошо. Может кто победил эту проблему?

Comment: Проект скорее всего жавовский. Вот он и не хватает их.
Если сделать проект C++ то он будет хватать C++ и С.
Как совместить это вместе я не знаю :(

Comment: Не совсем так. Настройки отдельные для Java и CDT

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй в настройках посмотреть

Window -> Preferences
Слева С -> C++ -> Editor -> Content Assist
Справа два поля, в которых нужно ткнуть типы контента, которые должны автодополняться и т.п.. Для Java нужно сделать то же самое если и для нее не работает.

Должно заработать.